# Way to avoid downloading file twice via IMAP

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm writing a script in Python that saves attachments from Gmail, only from unseen emails. To save on bandwidth I want to make sure that every file only gets downloaded once.

-I can't check the folder where I save them, because the file could be removed already, and then it shouldn't download again. (The scripts accesses the Inbox read_only, so it doesn't mark the email as read. As soon as the script runs again it will download the same attachments again, until the email gets marked read via another channel.)

-Right now I save the filename to a sqlite database, but there's 2 problems: I haven't figured out how to check the database for the filename the next time I run the script, and there's also a chance that somewhen down the line an attachment arrives with the same filename, which then wouldn't get downloaded.

What's a safe and scalable way to make sure I don't download the files more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not only save the filename to the database but save, for example, the Date:-header of the mail, too. (Or any combination of headers of which you are sure that they define a mail uniquely).

Comment: That would be the Message-id header.

Comment: and how would I call those? And like I said, I haven't figured out how to check the database for the filename (and in this case the message id as well), how would I do that?

Comment: executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE msgID = ?", msgID)

Answer (score 1):

There are several open source projects in Python that already perform this task very well.  Why don't you take a look at [OfflineIMAP](http://offlineimap.org/) and [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/)'s source code.  Also, if you're just trying to backup your GMail account, I suggest you use one of those rather than rolling your own...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch the headers for the message, and use the message's Date and/or Message-Id header value to construct a "unique id prefix" for all of the attachments in that message. Then create a key of the form `[unique_id]_[filename]`, check if that key exists in your database or filesystem. If not, download all attachments for that message, and save each with the modified unique id key.